# Selenium Python Chrome - "element not interactable"

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

Trying and failing to input text into the username and password text fields on this [page](https://auth.profiling.exemplarsystems.com.au/login?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fprofiling.exemplarsystems.com.au%2Fauth%2Flogin&response_type=code&client_id=4o5bgg3pbpkf6qkhhvuk7sqj2v&identity_provider=COGNITO&scope=phone%20email%20profile%20openid%20aws.cognito.signin.user.admin&state=Zz7yzeyookFaUxIqYZhbCJGxzQnrToMS&code_challenge=D1xphBZOLGOWN4n0r6YyZvKUz7rym6RRleb6ymHTLa4&code_challenge_method=S256):

I'm able to select the element but it throws the not interactable message.

I've tried:

#1

```
login_form = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id='signInFormUsername']")
login_form.send_keys('User')
```

#2

```
login_form = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id='signInFormUsername']")))
login_form.send_keys('User')
```

Any other means of sending text to this element?

Comment: you use headless mode?

Comment: no, I dont use headless mode

Comment: This exception occurs when an element is not visible to the selenium, so for that, you have to scroll toward the target element and perform the actions.

Comment: how do you scroll to the element in selenium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Root cause:** There are 2 elements with `@id=signInFormUsername`, you need to identify and locate the second element. Your code is trying to locate the first element, and the first element is not visible on browser, hence you are getting `Element not interactable` exception.

**Solution:** Using XPath locator strategy, use the below XPath expression to locate second element in the DOM:

```
(//input[@id='signInFormUsername'])[2]
```

**Code:**

```
login_form = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//input[@id='signInFormUsername'])[2]")))
login_form.send_keys('User')
```

**UPDATE:** How to find if XPath expression locates one or more elements:

Press key <kbd>F12</kbd> --> Press <kbd>Ctrl + F</kbd> on console and paste the XPath expression `//input[@id='signInFormUsername']`. You will notice 2 results as shown in below screenshot. First one won't highlight on the desired text box, but second one will. Try it.

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly. how did you identify that there is 2 elements of the same ID? and how did you see that one was hidden?

Comment: Check my updated answer. Follow the steps from there and let me know if that answered your questions.

Comment: perfectly clear.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 login elements and first element that actually returns `find_element` is invisible.
So, to solve your issue, you should filter by visible elements and get first visible element from array.

```py
login_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[name=username]')
login_input = [element for element in login_elements if element.is_displayed()][0]
login_input.send_keys('User')
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]
There are two elements that the website switches between in small or large size,
so if large try
`driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "form input[id='signInFormUsername']")[0].send_keys('User')`

or

`driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "form input[id='signInFormUsername']")[1].send_keys('User')`

Comment: Not the best approach. What if after some time elements position in array would change vice versa? 
Test would return false-negative result.